# Django Rest Framework serialization error: Object of type type is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json, django

I am new to both django and python and currently trying to implement a REST api using django-rest-framework. I know there are a lot of alike questions but they are serializing objects using .json, and i am not.

I have 2 models captain and boat as follows:

```
    //models.py
    from django.db import models

    class Captain(models.Model):
        name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False)
        last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False)
        government_id = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False, unique=True)
        company_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=False, unique=False)
        phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False, unique=False)
        tax_id = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False, unique=True)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

    class Boat(models.Model):
        captain = models.ForeignKey(Captain, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True, related_name='boats')
        name = models.CharField(max_length=55, blank=False)
        journey_type = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
        category = models.CharField(max_length=55, null=True, blank=True)
        passenger_capacity = models.IntegerField()
        crew_count = models.IntegerField()
        have_ac = models.IntegerField(default=0)
        year_built = models.DateField
        year_restored = models.DateField(blank=True)
        engine = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        generator = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
        width = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        height = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        length = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=True)
        wc_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
        master_cabin_count = models.IntegerField(null=True)
        standart_cabin_count = models.IntegerField(blank=False, null=False)
        date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
        date_modified = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

As you can see each boat has one captain and one captain can have many boats. So in database there is a captain_id field for Boat table. I have defined two serializers for each model:

```
    //serializers.py
    from rest_framework import serializers
    from .models import Captain, Boat

    class CaptainSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        class Meta:
            model = Captain
            fields = ('id', 'name', 'last_name', 'government_id', 'company_name', 'phone_number', 'tax_id', 'date_created', 'date_modified','boats')

    class BoatSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
        captain = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=False, read_only=True)

        class Meta:
            model = Boat
            fields = ('id', 'captain', 'name', 'journey_type', 'category', 'passenger_capacity', 'crew_count', 'have_ac', 'year_built', 'year_restored', 'wc_count', 'standart_cabin_count')
```

Then i have defined views for each model.
        //views.py
        from django.shortcuts import render
        from rest_framework import generics
        from .serializers import CaptainSerializer, BoatSerializer
        from .models import Captain, Boat

```
    class CaptainCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Captain.objects.all()
        serializer_class = CaptainSerializer

        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            serializer.save()

    class CaptainDetailsView(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
        lookup_field = 'pk'
        serializer_class = CaptainSerializer
        queryset = Captain.objects.all()

    class BoatCreateView(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
        queryset = Boat.objects.all()
        serializer_class = BoatSerializer

        def perform_create(self, serializer):
            serializer.save()
```

When i go to page localhost:port/captains/ (or /GET/captains from postman) i can have captain models including the boats he has.

But The problem is : when i go to localhost:port/boats (or postman) it gives,

Object of type type is not JSON serializable

Exception Type: TypeError at /boats/
Exception Value: Object of type type is not JSON serializable

Any ideas how can i fix this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll need to show your URLs and the full traceback.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the `year_built` field in the `Boat` model is not well defined (you're assigning the class `DateField` but not creating an instance of it):

```
class Boat(models.Model):
    year_built = models.DateField  # should be models.DateField()
```